# How to tell the difference between mould and condensed milk and sugar

Tags: food, mycology, milk

I have had sweetened condensed milk in the refrigerator for some weeks (or months perhaps?). The can was covered with aluminium foil.

I noticed some disk-like artefacts on its surface, which are harder then the rest of the product:

[image: condensed milk]

[Full-sized photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUPQ.jpg)

How can I know if this is mould or simply further condensed milk with sugar? Is this safe to eat?

If it is relevant: the content of sugar is 56 g per 100 g, while this product has 8 % of fat content.

Comment: You could try picking up a piece and putting on top of a slice of bread or some other nutrient in a sealable bag  and leave it on a counter overnight and see if it grows?

Comment: @Cell, that's a good idea, thanks!